# OpenCL on Android i.MX6 (udoo board)

Tags: android, linux, linker, opencl

As I'm trying to compare Renderscript and OpenCL, I want to get OpenCL working on the i.MX6 processor of the Udoo board.

I took the libOpenCL.so from a linux udoo installation and placed it onto the Android udoo board (since there was no libOpenCL.so on the Android version).
When I tried to load it, it missed these `library's: ld-2.15.so / ld-linux.so.3 / libc.so.6 / libc-2.15.so / librt.so.1 and librt-2.15.so`
I've found those library's on the Linux Udoo and moved them to the Android udoo board. But now I get this error:

> 01-02 00:01:12.810: E/dalvikvm(3206):
>   dlopen("/system/lib/libOpenCL.so") failed: Cannot load library:
>   soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library
>   "librt.so.1" needed by "libOpenCL.so"; caused by
>   soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libc.so.6"
>   needed by "librt.so.1"; caused by soinfo_relocate(linker.cpp:1178):
>   unknown reloc type 19 @ 0x689a13e0 (1193)

**What I've found online (not that much) told me that these .so files are compiled with a compiler for linux that is not supported on Android.**

I've also made posts about it on the freescale forum but I've got no reply.

**Q: does anyone have experience with OpenCL on Android on the i.MX6 (or udoo board) ? Or can help me look in the right direction?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A kind freescale employee has helped me on this mather and posted the library's needed for OpenCL compiling on Android on the udoo board.

The library's can be found here (for Android you need the libOpenCL.so): https://community.freescale.com/docs/DOC-93984